# Parsing .obj files with UV textures

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

### Bottom Line Up Front

With my 3D object (example a cube) on each side of the cube 1 triangle is being rendered correctly while the other side is not.

### Overview

I am attempting to import 3D objects created in Blender to my Android OpenGL world.

I wrote my own custom parser to read in the vertices, indicies and now the texture coordinates. I can read all the data in just fine and with out the textures, the shape is perfect. The problem is when I try to read in the texture coordinates, on every face one of the triangles is very screwed up while one of the triangles is being rendered correctly.

I believe this has something to do with how the texture coordinates are generated in blender.I noticed that in the part of the file `f 1/1 2/2 3/3 4/4` where it lists the "index of the texture" they are not lined up in the order that the textures are listed. Could that be the problem? If I build my texture buffer in the order that the texture indices are listed would that help?

### My .obj file

```
# Blender v2.63 (sub 0) OBJ File: ''
# www.blender.org
mtllib untitled.mtl
o Cube
v 1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 1.000000 -0.999999
v 0.999999 1.000000 1.000001
v -1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
vt 0.000000 0.334353
vt 0.332314 0.333333
vt 0.333333 0.665647
vt 0.001020 0.666667
vt 1.000000 0.001019
vt 0.998981 0.333333
vt 0.666667 0.332314
vt 0.667686 0.000000
vt 1.000000 0.665647
vt 0.667686 0.666667
vt 0.666667 0.334353
vt 0.334353 0.666667
vt 0.333333 0.334353
vt 0.665647 0.333333
vt 0.666667 0.665647
vt 0.333333 0.332314
vt 0.001020 0.333333
vt 0.000000 0.001020
vt 0.332314 0.000000
vt 0.333333 0.001019
vt 0.665647 0.000000
vt 0.334353 0.333333
usemtl Material_golden_fur_by_Dwaoviel.jpg
s off
f 1/1 2/2 3/3 4/4
f 5/5 8/6 7/7 6/8
f 1/6 5/9 6/10 2/11
f 2/12 6/13 7/14 3/15
f 3/16 7/17 8/18 4/19
f 5/20 1/21 4/7 8/22
```

### My Parser Method

```
public static Mesh createMesh(int resourceID)
{
    Mesh m = new Mesh();
    Scanner s;
    BufferedReader inputStream = null;
    
    ArrayList<Float> floats = new ArrayList<Float>();
    ArrayList<Short> indicies = new ArrayList<Short>();
    ArrayList<Float> textures = new ArrayList<Float>();
    ArrayList<Short> texturesindex = new ArrayList<Short>();
    try
    {
        inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(context.getResources().openRawResource(resourceID)));
        s = new Scanner(inputStream);
        String line = inputStream.readLine();
        line = inputStream.readLine();
        line = inputStream.readLine();
        line = inputStream.readLine();
        line = inputStream.readLine();
        while(line.charAt(0) == 'v'&&line.charAt(1)!='t')
        {
            s = new Scanner(line);
            s.next();
            floats.add(s.nextFloat());
            floats.add(s.nextFloat());
            floats.add(s.nextFloat());
            line = inputStream.readLine();
        }
        while(line.charAt(0)=='v' && line.charAt(1)=='t')
        {
            s = new Scanner(line);
            s.next(); //read in "vt"
            textures.add(s.nextFloat());
            textures.add(s.nextFloat());
            line = inputStream.readLine();
        }
        line = inputStream.readLine();
        line = inputStream.readLine();
        while(line != null && line.charAt(0) == 'f')
        {
            s = new Scanner(line);
            s.useDelimiter("[ /\n]");
            String xx = s.next();
            int a,b,c,d;
            int e,f,g,h;
            
            a = s.nextShort();
        
            e = s.nextShort();
            
            b = s.nextShort();
            
            f = s.nextShort();
            
            c = s.nextShort();
            
            g = s.nextShort();
            
            d = s.nextShort();
            
            h = s.nextShort();
            
            indicies.add((short)a);
            indicies.add((short)b);
            indicies.add((short)c);
            indicies.add((short)a);
            indicies.add((short)c);
            indicies.add((short)d);
            line = inputStream.readLine();
        }       
        float[] vertex = new float[floats.size()];
        for(int i=0;i<vertex.length;i++)
        {
            vertex[i] = floats.get(i).floatValue();
        }
        short[] ind = new short[indicies.size()];
        for(int i=0;i<ind.length;i++)
        {
            ind[i] = (short) (indicies.get(i).shortValue()-1); //minus one because its 1 based in that program
        }
        float[] texture = new float[floats.size()];
        for(int i=0;i<texture.length;i++)
        {
            texture[i] = textures.get(i).floatValue();
        }
        m.constructVertexBuffer(vertex);
        m.constructIndexBuffer(ind);
        m.constructTextureBuffer(texture);
        
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return m;
}
```

Note, this method basically reads in as many texture uv coordinates as there are into an array list and then populates a float array and then calls the construct Texture Buffer method which does all the ByteBuffer/FloatBuffer stuff required for OpenGL.

### My Construction Method

```
public void constructTextureBuffer(float[] texture)
{
    ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texture.length*4);
    vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    textureBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
    textureBuffer.put(texture);
    textureBuffer.position(0);
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas of what I could try to resolve this?

Comment: Have you manually checked the texture array to see if the texture coordinates are coming out right? It might be you need to use vertex normals

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I do read you code correctly, but i think the problem is in parsing the face command (`'f'` character). If you look inside [OBJ specification](http://www.martinreddy.net/gfx/3d/OBJ.spec) or to the article about obj format on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file), the face command is in format (in your case) `f v1/vt1 v2/vt2 v3/vt3 ...` which means that first is vertex coordinates index (into your list of vertex coordinates previously loaded) `'/'` then texture coordinates index (into your list of texture coordinates previously loaded). All those vertexes on one line after the `'f'` command creates one face (triangle, quad, etc).

Also doesn't matter if are those indexes to texture array (list) in same order as they were previously declared, it's just index (0 <= index < size of list).

Answer (score 0):

There is a few good FOSS OpenGL engines for Android out in the wild. While I can't give you an exact reason that your code is not functioning I do know that Rajawali's OBJ parser does a pretty good job especially with models exported from Blender. Maybe you can find some clues in their code:

https://github.com/MasDennis/Rajawali/blob/master/src/rajawali/parser/ObjParser.java

EDIT: I should also add that even in Rajawali I typically have to remove the two lines from my OBJ that look like this:
    `usemtl Material_golden_fur_by_Dwaoviel.jpg` and
    `s off`

Maybe your parser is not handling those well either?